# how to filter data in dcjs/crossfilter on selection of datatable row?

Tags: crossfilter, dc.js

I have seen most of the examples of dc.js which filters the data using brushes. How should i filter the data using the row element selected from datatable??

I am not sure of exact solution but some workaround may be done as

```
dimension.filter(value)
```

where value updated onclick? Am I going in right direction or is there a better way?

**Edit 1**
If i draw a row chart of the same thing with the then I don't have to handle onlcick event or anything but for datatable why is it comparatively so much complecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes I put a onclick="function(value)" button.

and

```
window.function(value){
    table.dimension(dimension);
    table.filter(value);
    table.render();
}
```

PS: I am not proficient in dc.js so this method might not be a optimal solution

Answer (score 0):

That should work. You will have to trigger the redraw events to the charts know about the change.