# Filter data by clicking data table row in dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I am trying to create a standardized dashboard using dc.js. One question that i require help with is if its possible to filter the visuals based on a selection of the data table rows. 
I am thinking of populating a table with unique column values and then using it to view filtered data.

I found a similar question here [how to filter data in dcjs/crossfilter on selection of datatable row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384104/how-to-filter-data-in-dcjs-crossfilter-on-selection-of-datatable-row)

Not sure if there is another way of doing it internally in dc.js and hence the question.

Here is a [sample dashboard made using spotfire](http://www.dashboardinsight.com/CMS/8cc63010-def8-41fb-b93c-507bafe3c03f/tibco.png). Here i can filter the data by selecting unique values from the filters on the right.

Thank you.

Comment: Nope, there is no built-in way to do this.

Comment: :(.. Any tips on how to achieve this? I am thinking of passing parametrized values using jquery and linking them to filters. Also what is written in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384104/how-to-filter-data-in-dcjs-crossfilter-on-selection-of-datatable-row is valid? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, I think that should work.  If you look at the onClick for the other charts they are doing pretty much this. I guess it depends what you want to filter on, since usually a filter is on a value for one column (dimension value(s)), whereas a data table usually contains individual rows. Filtering an individual row might or might not be useful.

Comment: This would be very usefull if bound to a search form like the default one of datatables. When you search for a keyword, the table is filtered but not the graphs.

Comment: Actually, I think I may have misunderstood because you mentioned a data table, so I thought you were talking about the data table built into dc.js. Reading your question more closely, I guess you are talking about populating a table with the unique keys from a group.  So I think it's very much like the multiple select menu widget in this PR: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/771

Comment: Indeed Gordon, thats the feature i was looking for. How do i use it now? Has it been committed to the dc.js repo?

Comment: Ahh.. Now i see. Should i copy the /select-menu.js file to my workspace or just copy the code in there to my dc.js file? Thoughts?

Comment: I think i cant edit my previous comments.The code works like a charm. I copy pasted the code in the dc.js file. @Gordon Kindly put in your comment as the answer and i will accept it :)

Comment: Glad I could help, and thanks for trying it out! Will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the multiple select menu widget which was contributed in this PR:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/771

This will be included in the 2.1 release of dc.js